# Why render speed change slow After setState?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a chat application. When I click the send button, if I use setState to clear the input box in my code, the input box becomes very jammed several times after sending a message. If I don't clear the input box after sending a message, there's no such problem. This problem has troubled me for a long time. I hope I can get your help. Thank you.

react-native:0.55.4
platform:android

chat page code:

```
render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior='position' contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}}

                keyboardVerticalOffset={px2dp((Platform.OS==='ios'?148:-632))}>
                <FlatList
                    ref='flatList'
                    style={{}}
                    data={this.state.msgList}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.msgId}
                    renderItem={({index, item}) => this.renderItem(index, item)}
                     automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                    initialNumToRender={8} 

                >
                </FlatList>

                <MessageInput onSend={this.onSend} onFocus={this.onFocus}/>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>)
    }
```

message input component code:

```
export default class MessageItem extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showEmoticons:false,
            message:"",
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
         return nextState.message!==this.state.message;
    }


    onChangeText=(message)=>{
        this.setState({message:message});
    }

    //Send message
    onSend=()=>{

        this.props.onSend&&this.props.onSend(this.state.message);

            **this.setState({message:""})**;// if add this line code,input box will change very slow


    }


    render(){

const msg=this.state.message;

        return (<View style={{
            padding: px2dp(50),
            paddingTop: px2dp(16),
            paddingBottom: px2dp(16),
            bottom:this.state.showEmoticons?300:0,
            height:px2dp(110),
            backgroundColor:'#e5e5e7',
            flexDirection:'row',
            alignItems:'center',
            justifyContent:'center'
        }}>
            <MaterialIcon name="keyboard-voice" size={px2dp(55)} onPress={this.onSearch}
                          style={{textAlign: "center",marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}} color="#111111"/>
            <TextInput  ref='msgInput' value={msg} style={{
                height: px2dp(80),
                borderRadius: px2dp(10),
                borderColor:'white',
                backgroundColor:'white',
                fontSize:12,


                lineHeight: px2dp(36),
                padding: px2dp(20),
                borderWidth: 1,
                width:(msg.length>0?(width-px2dp(55)*2-px2dp(119)-50):(width-px2dp(55)*3-50)),

            }} placeholder='我来说两句'
                        multiline={true}
                        returnKeyType='default'
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        onChangeText={this.onChangeText}


            />
            <SimpleLineIcon name="emotsmile" size={px2dp(55)} onPress={this.onShowEmoticons}
                            style={{textAlign: "center",marginLeft:10}} color="#111111"/>

            {msg.length>0?<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSend}>
                <View style={styles.sendMsgContainer}><Text style={styles.sendMsgBtn}>发送</Text></View>
            </TouchableOpacity>:<AntDesignIcon name="pluscircleo" size={px2dp(55)} onPress={this.onSearch}
                                               style={{textAlign: "center",marginLeft:10,marginRight:10}} color="#111111"/>}
        </View>)


    }
}
```

when I use add 'this.setState({message:""});' code to onSend function, the input box becomes very jammed several times after sending a message

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know this problem

Comment: never mind ,thank you all the same